# Why is the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ of $(\phi(x)-\phi(-x))/x$ well defined if $\phi$ is a smooth function with compact support?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am trying to understand the proof that the principal value of 1/x is a distribution :
[image]

Ok so I understand that we decomposed $\phi$ into its even and odd part and the odd part disappeared so we are left with the even part. The part I don't understand exactly is why we are able to say that $\lim \epsilon \to 0^+$ of $\int_{\varepsilon}^\infty \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(-x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$ is in fact $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(-x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$. How do we know the integral does not blow up to infinity as we take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$?

Comment: Recall that $\varphi$ has compact support, so the integral is over a domain of finite measure. Now apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @fwd Hi, im sorry but I don't quite understand how we apply the DCT here. The dct just lets us swith the order of limits and integration for sequence of functions that are dominated by another integrable function right? Are we just taking $\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(-x)}{x}$ and multiplying it be the characteristic function on [0,n] and we take that as our sequence? Then what would our dominating function be?

Comment: for $x$ small enough $\frac{\phi(x)-]phi(-x)}{x}\approx 2\phi'(0)$ Defining $\psi(x)=\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(-x)}{x}$ for $x\neq0$ and $\psi(0)=2\phi'(0)$ yields a continuous function. Notice the integration can be reduced to $\int^A_\varepsilon\psi(x)\,dx$ for some $A$ large enough.

Comment: @,Bill yes. The dominator is just a constant which is integrable on a finite domain.